# how to use Pandas to only read excel header?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I know read excel table with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_excel(io)
```

After loading the data, if I want to get the table header:

```
table.columns
```

This method is feasible, but sometimes I just want to get the header of the excel table directly, especially when the excel table has a large body size, it will be very time-consuming to load the data table into the memory & it is also unnecessary, sometimes it even overflows directly and gets stuck. Looking at the official documents, it seems that I can use the `nrows` parameter to specify that only specific lines of Excel can be read, This means that I can use it to read only the first row header:

```
header = pd.read_excel(io, nrows = 0)
```

However, I found that also can not prevent pandas read the whole excel data, and it will still consume a lot of time and memory. Do you have good experience in dealing with this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading column names alone in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836781/reading-column-names-alone-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: No, xlsx file is different

Comment: So only the file extension changes, try that code after changing the file extension.

Comment: have a look at this library and see if it helps [pyexcel](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xlsxr)

Answer (score 2):

This function `sheet_rows` uses `openpyxl` directly, not `pandas`;
it's much faster than `read_excel( nrows=0 )`, and simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import openpyxl  # https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io

#...............................................................................
def sheet_rows( sheet, nrows=3, ncols=None, verbose=5 ) -> "list of lists":
    """ openpyxl sheet -> the first `nrows` rows x `ncols` columns
        verbose=5: print A1 .. A5, E1 .. E5 as lists
    """
    rows = sheet.iter_rows( max_row=nrows, max_col=ncols, values_only=True )
    rows = [list(r) for r in rows]  # generator -> list of lists
    if verbose:
        print( "\n-- %s  %d rows  %d cols" % (
                sheet.title, sheet.max_row, sheet.max_column ))
        for row in rows[:verbose]:
            trimNone = list( filter( None, row[:verbose] ))
            print( trimNone )
    return rows


# xlsxin = sys.argv[1]
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook( xlsxin, read_only=True )
print( "\n-- openpyxl.load_workbook( \"%s\" )" % xlsxin )

for sheetname in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[sheetname]

    rows = sheet_rows( sheet, nrows=nrows )

    df = (pd.DataFrame( rows )  # index= columns=
            .dropna( axis="index", how="all" )
            .dropna( axis="columns", how="all" ) 
            )
    print( df )
    # df.to_excel df.to_csv ...
```

"Partial read" under [pyexcel](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel)
explains that most Excel readers
read ALL the data into memory before doing anything else -- slow.
`openpyxl iter_rows()` gets a few rows or columns fast, memory don't know.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd 
Frame = pd.read_excel("/content/data.xlsx", header=0)
print(Frame.head(0))
```

This will give you the header only, assuming the header is on row `1`. If no value is entered, the default value of `5` is assumed. Hence that is why you obtain multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 

Frame=pd.read_excel("/content/data.xlsx" , header=0)
Frame.head()
```

Comment: thanks, but I just want to get the header only, This method still takes a lot of time and memory to read the whole data